systemrescue: testdisk doesn't find huge amount of deleted files
i accidently deleted a huge folder structure of my data on my notebook and emptied in a foolish manner my trash-bin without looking at the ~20GiB of data!
My last (dirvish-) backup was a few month ago, so much of my work since then is gone.
On another machine i created an actual system-rescue Live-Stick, booted the notebook with the stick and created a 'gzip'-compressed image of the '/home'-Partition (/dev/nvme0n1p7) on an external usb-drive (/dev/sdb3).
mkdir /mnt/Videos.tmp
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Videos.tmp

dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p7 bs=1M|pv|gzip -cf - > /mnt/Videos.tmp/K_home.dd.gz

Since the '/home'-Partition is about 230GiB, i wanted to decompress the image 'on-the-fly' and tried the methods described at How to mount a compressed Image.
I'm trying to recover the lost data width testdisk an other tools for a week now.
Booted into the live-system i tried the 'nbd-server' / '-client'-access to the compressed image with:
[root@sysrescue ~]# nbd-server 127.0.0.1 /mnt/K_home/K_home.dd.gz -r --dont-fork

** (process:8265): WARNING **: 07:03:33.385: Specifying an export on the command line no longer uses the oldstyle protocol.
[root@sysrescue ~]#

In another terminal i tried to listen with the client:
[root@sysrescue ~]# nbd-client 127.0.0.1 -nofork -readonly
Warning: the oldstyle protocol is no longer supported.
This method now uses the newstyle protocol with a default export
Error: Socket failed: Connection refused
[root@sysrescue ~]# 

Any help would be appreciated.
With the nbd-Server/-client installation on the sysrescue-Stick there might be a problem with wrong user-rights, if you have a look at the config-file:
[root@sysrescue ~]# cat /etc/nbd-server/config  [generic]
# The [generic] section is required, even if nothing is specified
# there.
# When either of these options are specified, nbd-server drops
# privileges to the given user and group after opening ports, but
# _before_ opening files
user = nbd
group = nbd [export1]
exportname = /export/nbd/export1-file
authfile = /export/nbd/export1-authfile
timeout = 30
filesize = 10000000
readonly = false
multifile = false
copyonwrite = false
prerun = dd if=/dev/zero of=%s bs=1k count=500
postrun = rm -f %s [otherexport]
exportname = /export/nbd/experiment
# The other options are all optional. 
[root@sysrescue ~]#

